# Movie where a girl helps an injured bird and receives gifts from it

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I don’t remember details but I remember that a bird was injured and a girl (I think that she was poor) saved the bird and in exchange the bird gave her a lot of things.

It was not a normal bird. The bird gave her a big house and luck and things like that.

I remember that a guy, later, knowing what the bird gave the girl, purposefully injured  the wing of the same bird, treating him right after, hoping that he would be given things too.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Do you remember whether there were any science fiction or fantasy elements to this story? Right now, I'm not sure whether this would be on-topic or not. Birds are known for bringing people objects in real life, so that alone wouldn't be enough to make it fantasy.

Comment: This does sound like a common fairy tale template.

Comment: It was not a normal bird, the bird gave her a big house and luck and things lile that

Comment: @Laurel those are small enough amounts of fantasy that I think this is still off-topic.

Comment: @Stormblessed The description reminds me of Aladdin, except it's a bird instead of a genie in a lamp and there's probably no flying carpet either :P

Comment: When did you watched? and where ? (tv,video, cinema), its an interesting question.